# Ida+Windbg alternative of Olly's "Back to user code" feature

Tags: ida, ollydbg, windbg

I'm learning lena151's materials and in 4 lesson she uses Olly's Back-to-user feature to find where the MassegeBox is creating.

[image]

It works fine under x32 windows server 2003.

But what about nowadays?!

Is there similar option in IDA+WINDBG for x64 apps?
Coz I've tried setting BP to the .text section but I faced the message of IDA 'BP set is failed coz of break point overlapping' (so you should delete all previous if some was set)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got found incredibly good plugin for IDA.

The tools:

1. PixtopianBook.exe (lena151's 4th tutorial).
2. IDA 7.6 x86.
3. Funcap python script for ida.

The task:
Do any action and find out which function was called.

The recipe:

**1. Get the script by typing** `git clone https://github.com/deresz/funcap.git`

**2. Run IDA and select the Local Windows debugger (Windbg froze up when launch with lots of breakpoints).**

> [image]

**3. Run process as usual, right till the exe fully loads up.**

> [image]

**4. Pause process, hold ALT+F7 and select `funcap.py` script**

> [image]

**5. Now type in command line `d.hookSeg('.text')` and run process.**

> [image]

**6. Now just click the interesting button and wait till it fully drawn.**

> [image]

**7. You will see a lot of logs in the IDA output, select and copy whole text to some notepad and search for `MessageBox`. Here we go :з**

> [image]